# callback function value access into other function in nodejs

Tags: node.js, callback

When my callback function (`setid`) calls another function (`returnbCallback`), but the data isn't passed and I see a value of "null".

```
var swfitprofileName = [];

function setid (swiftid){

  crud.getswift(swiftid).then(function (response) {
    returnbCallback(response);
  }).catch(function (err) {
    return ("error:" + err);
  });

}

function returnbCallback(data){
  console.log("profileName1",swfitprofileName);
  return swfitprofileName = data;
}

console.log("swfitprofileName",swfitprofileName);
```

How do I access the callback results in another function?

Comment: Question is not clear, please what do you want in an output.